# Add user meta fields on creating the user

Tags: user-meta

I have made a file where I am adding user meta fields but they are only added for a user on update. They are not added when I am creating the user. This is the file:

```
<?php
add_action('init', function() {
  /**
   * Add new fields above 'Update' button.
   *
   * @param WP_User $user User object.
   */
  function additional_profile_fields( $user ) {

      $departments = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'department', 'hide_empty' => false]);
      $userDepartment = get_the_author_meta( 'department', $user->ID );
      $regions = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'region', 'hide_empty' => false]);
      $userRegion = get_the_author_meta( 'region', $user->ID );
      $industries = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'industry', 'hide_empty' => false]);
      $userIndustry = get_the_author_meta( 'industry', $user->ID );
      $companies = get_terms(['taxonomy' => 'company', 'hide_empty' => false]);
      $userCompany = get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID );

      ?>
      <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
      <table class="form-table">
       <tr>
         <th><label for="department">Avdeling</label></th>
         <td>
           <select id="department" name="department">
             <option value="">Velg alternativ</option>
             <?php
               foreach ( $departments as $department ) {
                 printf( '<option value="%1$s" %2$s>%1$s</option>', $department->name, selected( $userDepartment, $department->name, false ) );
               }
             ?>
          </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="form-table">
       <tr>
         <th><label for="region">Region</label></th>
         <td>
           <select id="region" name="region">
               <option value="">Velg alternativ</option>
               <?php
               foreach ( $regions as $region ) {
                 printf( '<option value="%1$s" %2$s>%1$s</option>', $region->name, selected( $userRegion, $region->name, false ) );
               }
             ?>
           </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="form-table">
       <tr>
         <th><label for="industry">Bransje</label></th>
         <td>
           <select id="industry" name="industry">
              <option value="">Velg alternativ</option>
              <?php
               foreach ( $industries as $industry ) {
                 printf( '<option value="%1$s" %2$s>%1$s</option>', $industry->name, selected( $userIndustry, $industry->name, false ) );
               }
             ?>
           </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="form-table">
       <tr>
         <th><label for="company">Selskap</label></th>
         <td>
           <select id="company" name="company">
             <option value="">Velg alternativ</option>
             <?php
               foreach ( $companies as $company ) {
                 printf( '<option value="%1$s" %2$s>%1$s</option>', $company->name, selected( $userCompany, $company->name, false ) );
               }
             ?>
           </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <?php
  }

  function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'department', $_POST['department'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'region', $_POST['region'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'company', $_POST['company'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'industry', $_POST['industry'] );
  }

  add_action('user_new_form', 'additional_profile_fields');
  add_action('edit_user_profile', 'additional_profile_fields');
  add_action('show_user_profile', 'additional_profile_fields');
  add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
  add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
});
```

How can I save those meta fields on initial creation of an user, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing one more action, that is fired when new user is created:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'save_extra_profile_fields', 10, 1 );
```

documented in [wordpress codex.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/)